# Apache not allowing access to sub directories

Tags: apache

I installed Apache2, php, and mysql onto my Linux Mint machine with the hopes of continuing a website I had built. After copy and pasting all of the code I had I noticed a problem with one of my include statments:

```
<?php include("./dir/file1.html");
```

That wasn't working. Originally I thought the issue was with php but after a lot of trial and error I've concluded it's apache not allowing access to subdirectories in the /var/www/ directory.

Since I'm new to editing apache configuration files, I'm not really sure what to change to allow access to all subdirectories within /var/www/ on localhost. I've tried adding:

```
<Directory /var/www/*>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

to my httpd.conf file (which was blank, which I learned had something to do with Linux Mint being Debian based) and confirmed that default in /sites-available had similar code. I'll post that if it's requested.

I'm unsure on what else I can do to get apache to allow access to subdirectories in my /var/www/ directory for localhost and none of my previous methods have worked.

**UPDATE:**

I believe it's an Apache issue because when trying to go to a subdirectory through the browser (like localhost/dir/), I get a 403 error. I don't have to be going to an actual webpage for that problem. Also, include statments including files in the current directory has no problem, only with subdirectories.

The Include statement above gives no errors or any other useful messages. Whatever the include statement is including is just not there. I've tried require but that gives me a 500 server error: the server may be down for maintenance (paraphrased).

Comment: Who is the owner of the subdirectories?

Comment: I'm the owner of the subdirectories and everything has read permission at least.

Comment: What user is Apache running as?

Comment: do the sub-directories have any .htaccess files in them?

Comment: Can you say what led you to think it was an Apache problem? Is there any error output to the browser or to the error logs? I highly suspect this is actually a PHP thing -- once you're in a PHP script, the apache config doesn't really apply anymore.

Comment: There are no .htaccess files in the subdirectories.

I believe it's an Apache problem because when trying to navigate to the subdirectories through my browser I get a 403 Forbidden error. Php wouldn't give that, but Apache would. 

I don't know how to find out what user Apache is running, but all subdirectories have read permissions across the board.

Comment: The reason it's probably not an apache issue is because in the above code, apache isn't browsing to that subdirectory -- PHP is. It doesn't really matter that you can't get to the file in apache. If you wanted to, you could call <?php include "/totally/other/place/file.php"; ?> and if PHP setup allowed that, it would work just fine. Also, you didn't say what actually happens when you run the above code.